# On Maintaining Unique Scope between server and client. Still it reflect same data on sync with another client as i syn with first one. Why?

Tags: frameworks, synchronization

I have create Scope different between each client and one server in scope_info table in DB. Once i sync with first client on filter condition it work correct but on changing filter condition with another client still it sync same data as i get previously. My code as given below :

Here Value is Unique Identity of Client.
Code:

```
            ArrayList UnSyncTable = new ArrayList();
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(ClientString);
            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(ServerString);

            for (int i = 0; i < ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                #region Start Sync
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                if (serverConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    serverConn.Open();
                }

                if (clientConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    clientConn.Open();
                }
                try
                {

                    #region Step1 for ServerSide

                    DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "_SyncScope" + Value);

                    DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), serverConn);

                    scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);

                    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc);

                    serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

                    #region Filter Condition
                    if (DBFilteredTables.Contains(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()))
                    {
                        serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
                        serverProvision.Tables[ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()].AddFilterColumn(AttributeName);
                        serverProvision.Tables[ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()].FilterClause = "[side].[" + AttributeName + "] =" + Value;

                    }
                    #endregion

                    // start the provisioning process
                    serverProvision.Apply();
                    #endregion

                }
                catch
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    #region Step2 for ClientSide
                    DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc1 = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "_SyncScope" + Value, serverConn);

                    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc1);

                    clientProvision.Apply();
                    #endregion
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    #region Step3
                    SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

                    syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "_SyncScope" + Value, clientConn);

                    syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "_SyncScope" + Value, serverConn);

                    if (SyncCondition == 1)
                        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Download;
                    else if (SyncCondition == 2)
                        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;
                    else if (SyncCondition == 3)
                        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
                    else if (SyncCondition == 4)
                        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

                    ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

                    SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();


                    //print statistics
                    string Msg = "Start Time : " + syncStats.SyncStartTime + "\n";
                    Msg += "Table Name : " + ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "\n";
                    Msg += "Total Changes Uploaded : " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal + "\n";
                    Msg += "Total Changes Downloaded : " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal + "\n";
                    Msg += "Complete Time : " + syncStats.SyncEndTime + "\n";

                    #endregion
                }
                catch
                {
                    UnSyncTable.Add(ClientDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }

                #endregion

            }
```